# How can I open View PDF in the page the cursor is at TexMakerX?

Tags: pdf, forward-inverse-search, texstudio

I've been using TexMakerX for about a week. In the document I'm producing, I use pdfLaTeX (<kbd>F6</kbd>) to generate the output file, and then I use View PDF (<kbd>F7</kbd>).

When I use View PDF, it's supposed to open at the page the cursor is at TexMakerX, but this doesn't happen for my document anymore. It used to work, but it just stopped working without apparent reason.

When I open other documents, it works as expected.

What can I do to force View PDF open in the current page of the cursor?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from Stack Overflow. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Try removing any spaces in the file name - worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

TeXMakerX was renamed to [TeXStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/). The new version of [TeXStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/#downloads) has an internal viewer which supports `synctex`. You should install the new version instead using an old one.